# Edited: How can I change date format of Date object?

Tags: java, android, date

I have created table in SQLite database using this query:

```
create table table_name(
id integer primary key autoincrement,
name varchar(450) not null,
date date)
```

And I'm inserting values via this code (simplified for question):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date tmpDate = dateFormat.parse("2014/01/12");
values.put(columnKey, tmpDate.toString());
db.insert("table_name", null, values);
```

and after getting again value of row 'date' from database I'm getting this error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 EST 2014" (at offset 0)
```

If I save date with format yyyy/MM/dd shouldn't it be stored with the same format?
Thanks from advice.

Edit:
I have no idea why but after this:

```
DatePicker tmpDatePicker = (DatePicker) dateDialog.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date tmpDate = dateForma.parse("2014-01.12");
tmpDate.toString();
```

Output is Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 EST 2014.
How can I change it?

Comment: I have get rid off that error after using getLong insted of getString but still I can't change format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23048068/642706) is correct.

But I must say that the java.util.Date, .Calendar, and java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes are notoriously troublesome. Most folks are glad to avoid them and instead use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (or the new java.time package in Java 8 but not Android).

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) 2.3 offers a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class for working with date only, without a time portion or time zone.

Joda-Time by default uses the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard way to format string representations of date-time values, apparently what you seek. If needed Joda-Time can use localized or custom formats as well.

```
String input = "2014-01-12";
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( input );
String output = localDate.toString();
```

You can convert to and from a java.util.Date as needed for other classes/frameworks.

```
java.util.Date date = localDate.toDate();
String dateAsString = date.toString();
```

When run…

```
input: 2014-01-12
output: 2014-01-12
dateAsString: Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 PST 2014
```

Comment: @up: A lot of thanks bro! I have tried it out and it works perfectly. Just for such answers I love stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. toString() method sets format to Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 EST 2014.
To get format equals to given in SimpleDateFormat constructor pattern I needed to use this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date tmpDate = dateFormat.parse("2014-01-12");
dateFormat.format(tmpDate);
```

And output is 2014-01-12